# Optimize function creation and subsequent autocomplete configuration with a hash table

Tags: powershell, function, hashtable, powershell-7.0

### Primary Question

My question is whether it is possible to optimize the creation of functions and subsequent autocomplete settings with a hash table.

The Functions I want to optimize e.g. with a `ForEach` over the hash table below:

```
Function wu([string]$PackageName) {winget upgrade --include-unknown $PackageName}
Function wui([string]$PackageName) {winget upgrade -i $PackageName}
Function wi([string]$PackageName) {winget install $PackageName}
Function wii([string]$PackageName) {winget install -i -e $PackageName}
Function ws([string]$PackageName) {winget search $PackageName}
```

The subsequent autocomplete settings where I have adjusted `-CommandName` and `"$Local:ast".Replace('wu ', 'winget upgrade ')"` for the `wu` function I created, need to be adjusted for every other `Function` above. Source for original autocomplete is https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/blob/master/doc/Completion.md

As far as I understand I would need to create this for every single `Function`. I'd like to optimize that e.g. with a `ForEach`call as well:

```
Register-ArgumentCompleter -Native -CommandName wu -ScriptBlock {
    param($wordToComplete, $commandAst, $cursorPosition)
        [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = $OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Utf8Encoding]::new()
        $Local:word = $wordToComplete.Replace('"', '""')
        $Local:ast = $commandAst.ToString().Replace('"', '""')
        winget complete --word="$Local:word" --commandline "$Local:ast".Replace('wu ', 'winget upgrade ') --position $cursorPosition | ForEach-Object {
            [System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult]::new($_, $_, 'ParameterValue', $_)
        }
}
```

This is the hash table I created where I'm not able to properly use them for the creation of the `Function`s and autocomplete configurations:

```
$functions = @{
    "wu" = "winget upgrade --include-unknown";
    "wui" = "winget upgrade -i -e";
    "wi" = "winget install -i";
    "wii" = "winget install -i -e";
    "ws" = "winget search"
}
```

I tried something like this for creating functions, but it didn't evaluate the expressions:

```
ForEach($item in $functions.keys) {                                                   
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert("Function $item ([string]$PackageName) {$($functions[$item])}")
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::AcceptLine()
}
```

---

---

### Secondary question (Answered)

I still have two code blocks for the autocomplete section. One for the original `winget` command (with `-CommandName winget` and `--commandline "$Local:ast"`) and one for my hash table commands (with `-CommandName $funcName` and `--commandline "$Local:new_ast"`. Can I neatly combine them into one code blocks:

```
# Hashtable autocomplete configuration
foreach($funcName in $functions.PSBase.Keys){
    Register-ArgumentCompleter -Native -CommandName $funcName -ScriptBlock {
    param($wordToComplete, $commandAst, $cursorPosition)
        [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = $OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Utf8Encoding]::new()
        $Local:word = $wordToComplete.Replace('"', '""')
        $Local:ast = $commandAst.ToString().Replace('"', '""')
        $Local:new_ast = $Local:ast -replace '^w[uis]{1,2}\b', {
            if($functions.ContainsKey($_.Value)){ return $functions[$_.Value] } return $_.Value
        }
        winget complete --word="$Local:word" --commandline "$Local:new_ast" --position $cursorPosition | ForEach-Object {
            [System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult]::new($_, $_, 'ParameterValue', $_)
        }
    }
}

# Original autocomplete configuration
Register-ArgumentCompleter -Native -CommandName winget -ScriptBlock {
    param($wordToComplete, $commandAst, $cursorPosition)
        [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = $OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Utf8Encoding]::new()
        $Local:word = $wordToComplete.Replace('"', '""')
        $Local:ast = $commandAst.ToString().Replace('"', '""')
        winget complete --word="$Local:word" --commandline "$Local:ast" --position $cursorPosition | ForEach-Object {
            [System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult]::new($_, $_, 'ParameterValue', $_)
        }
}
```

I think something like this might work, because `winget` would be ignored by the regex since it's not in the functions hash table. But I can't figure out the syntax because the type is `KeyCollection`:

```
foreach($funcName in $($functions.PSBase.Keys + @{'winget'}))
```

---

---

### Answer

The finished result in my `$PROFILE` thanks to [@mathias-r-jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen):

```
$functions = @{
    "wu" = "winget upgrade --include-unknown";
    "wui" = "winget upgrade -i -e";
    "wi" = "winget install -i";
    "wii" = "winget install -i -e";
    "ws" = "winget search"
}

foreach($funcName in $functions.PSBase.Keys){
    New-Item function:\ -Name $funcName -Value $([scriptblock]::Create($functions[$funcName])) | Out-Null
}

foreach($funcName in @($functions.PSBase.Keys; 'winget')){
    Register-ArgumentCompleter -Native -CommandName $funcName -ScriptBlock {
    param($wordToComplete, $commandAst, $cursorPosition)
        [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = $OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Utf8Encoding]::new()
        $Local:word = $wordToComplete.Replace('"', '""')
        $Local:ast = $commandAst.ToString().Replace('"', '""')
        $Local:new_ast = $Local:ast -replace '^w[uis]{1,2}\b', {
            if($functions.ContainsKey($_.Value)){ return $functions[$_.Value] } return $_.Value
        }
        winget complete --word="$Local:word" --commandline "$Local:new_ast" --position $cursorPosition | ForEach-Object {
            [System.Management.Automation.CompletionResult]::new($_, $_, 'ParameterValue', $_)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Registering functions programmatically is as straightforward as creating new items in the `functions:` drive:

```
$functions = @{
    "wu" = "winget upgrade --include-unknown";
    "wui" = "winget upgrade -i -e";
    "wi" = "winget install -i";
    "wii" = "winget install -i -e";
    "ws" = "winget search"
}

foreach($funcName in $functions.PSBase.Keys){
  New-Item function:\ -Name $funcName -Value $functions[$funcName]
}
```

This will register all key-value entries from the table using the key as then function name, and the value as the source code for the function body.

Make sure you execute this code in the global scope (ie. by calling the registration code from a profile script or by explicitly exporting the resulting functions if part of a module).

For the argument completer, use the `-replace` to search for any 2- or 3-letter word beginning with `w`, then use a scriptblock as a match evaluator to lookup the correct translation:

```
$functions = @{
    "wu" = "winget upgrade --include-unknown";
    "wui" = "winget upgrade -i -e";
    "wi" = "winget install -i";
    "wii" = "winget install -i -e";
    "ws" = "winget search"
}

$commandLine = 'wu somePackage'

$commandLine -replace '^w[uis]{1,2}\b', {
  if($functions.ContainsKey($_.Value)){
    return $functions[$_.Value]
  }

  return $_.Value
}
```

`$translated` now holds the string value `"winget upgrade --include-unknown somePackage"`

---

In PowerShell versions prior to 6.1, you can achieve the same by directly invoking `[regex]::Replace()`:

```
$functions = @{
    "wu" = "winget upgrade --include-unknown";
    "wui" = "winget upgrade -i -e";
    "wi" = "winget install -i";
    "wii" = "winget install -i -e";
    "ws" = "winget search"
}

$commandLine = 'wu somePackage'

$translated = [regex]::Replace($commandLine, '^w[uis]{1,2}\b', {
  param($match)

  if($functions.ContainsKey($match.Value)){
    return $functions[$match.Value]
  }

  return $match.Value
})
```

Comment: I was as far as creating the necessary string values. I should have mentioned that, but I'm not sure how I would create `Function`s based on that.
I added some clarification to my question above.

Comment: @DmitrijDrandarov `New-Item` is your friend, I've updated the answer :)

Comment: Thanks! The translation works for getting the `--commandLine` argument.
I only had one other problem: `New-Item` printed all the functions, I fixed it by casting it to void:
`[void](New-Item function:\...)`
I'll add the finished code to my question and mark yours as the answer. :)

Comment: @DmitrijDrandarov Piping to `Out-Null` will have a similar effect: `New-Item ... |Out-Null`

Comment: Is there any benefit with that? I've read that void is supposedly faster.
Apart from that I'd have a secondary question: Do you have an idea how to combine the autocomplete configuration for the original `winget` command (https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/blob/master/doc/Completion.md) with my result?

Comment: @DmitrijDrandarov `Out-Null` _used to be_ very slow, but in PowerShell 7 it shouldn't make a significant difference. [Test it if you want to see for yourself](https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/610deb873a96f331039d) :) I'm not sure what you mean by combining "the autocomplete configuration [...] with my result"...

Comment: I've added it under "Secondary question" in my original post. :)

Comment: @mklement0 Cheers, I've simplified the sample code in my answer :)

Comment: I found that I can use `Out-String` to convert(?) the `KeyCollection` into something appendable: `foreach($funcName in $($functions.PSBase.Keys | Out-String) + 'winget'){`

Edit:
Just putting it into `$()`is enough: `$($functions.PSBase.Keys) + 'winget'`

Comment: `foreach($funcName in @($functions.PSBase.Keys;'winget')){ ... }` :)